Riemannian structure on the Heisenberg group.
Currently I am reading about Heisenberg Group. And I understand that this group is one of the simplest examples of sub-Riemannian manifolds. I have read a lot about it structure, geodesics and e.t.c. Mostly from this Lecture Notes (attached below):  https://cvgmt.sns.it/media/doc/paper/5339/sub-Riem_notes.pdf
But now I do not clearly understand, why we restrict the bundle and work on the Horizontal sub-bundle in case of the Heisenberg group. Why it is said that we cannot move directly along the Z-coordinate?
If you can share any materials or thoughts about this issue I will be very grateful!

Welcome to Math StackExchange. It's best practice to include explicit information about your question rather than referencing a text. This makes the question more searchable and increases the probability that someone will answer it!

Your title should be sub-Riemannian structure which is the main topic of Le Donne's notes which you can also follow on some very good Youtube videos. A good motivation for sub-Riemannian geometry is Dido's problem which is also contained in those notes. It is worth spending a lot of time with this. Having said that: the Heisenberg group admits also a quite natural Riemannian metric which leads to a scalar curvature of $-1/2,.$ An entirely different topic.
